# closing fancy box from its own iframe page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fancybox

i have opened fancy box with following code

```
       $("#tip5").fancybox({
            'width': 400,
            'height': 370,
            'enableEscapeButton' : false,
            'overlayShow' : true,
            'overlayOpacity' : 0,
            'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
            'type': 'iframe',
            'href': "abc.php?id=20"
        });
```

**abc.php** is opening in fancy box and working fine.

but i want to close this fancybox from  **abc.php** after specific time and i have written following code in **abc.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){                            
 setTimeout(function() {
                $.fancybox.close();
                }, 3000);
    });
```

i also tried

```
$.fn.fancybox.close()
```

its not closing but i am getting following error

```
$.fancybox is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

See [this page](http://fancybox.net/#various5) and click the link 'Iframe (75% width and height)'